# Reactjs prevent form submission not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, reload, preventdefault

I'm following a tutorial and I'm trying to have a form that does not reload when submitted to do this I'm trying to use `e.preventDefault();` however this is not working and the page is reloading on submission anyway

here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

function Modal() {

    const [Email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [Fact, setFact] = useState('');
    const [Source, setSource] = useState('');

    const handelSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newFact = {Email, Fact, Source};
        console.log(newFact);
    }

  return (
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add a Fact</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form onsubmit={handelSubmit}>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="InputEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="enter your email..." value={Email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} required></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="InputFact" class="form-label">Fact</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFact" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="enter your fact..." value={Fact} onChange={(e) => setFact(e.target.value)} required></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="InputSource" class="form-label">Source</label>
                        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="InputSource" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="enter your source..." value={Source} onChange={(e) => setSource(e.target.value)} required></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

the only major thing different that I'm doing from the tutorial is using a bootstrap 5 modal, but I don't think that this would cause the problem

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJiRj02PkJQ
And heres a link to the source code of that tutorial: https://github.com/iamshaunjp/Complete-React-Tutorial/blob/lesson-28/dojo-blog/src/Create.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in `onsbumit`. Change it to `onSubmit`. Remember that React is using JSX, so even though the code looks like HTML, it is actually JavaScript.

Comment: Please may you flag the question as a typo?